# SQL error in matlab

Tags: sql, image, matlab, ms-access

I am new to sql ,

can somebody help me what is error in this.

I am executing this in matlab.

```
     exec(conn,'CREATE TABLE idb (Id int,Photo varbinary(max))')
```

ans =

```
    Attributes: []
          Data: 0
DatabaseObject: [1x1 database]
      RowLimit: 0
      SQLQuery: 'CREATE TABLE idb (Id int,Photo varbinary(max))'
       Message: '[Microsoft][ODBC dBase Driver] Syntax error in field definition.'
          Type: 'Database Cursor Object'
     ResultSet: 0
        Cursor: 0
     Statement: 0
         Fetch: 0
```

Comment: I created ".mdb" from Microsoft access

Comment: What is the photo? Do you want a memo data type or OLE?

Comment: I am trying to save .jpg image,i tried "image" datatype also

Answer (score 0):

It worked with below code

```
    exec(conn,'CREATE TABLE idb(Id int,Photo image)')
```

Comment: It is not recommended to store images in MS Access, especially versions prior to 2007. You should just store an image path. Storing images can lead to severe bloat.

Comment: but i want to store image,how to do it efficiently.

Comment: If you really must, you can write a blob ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/103257 ) but you would  be much better off just storing a path to the image. Why do you want to store an image in a database?

Comment: i want to save images for image processing.

Comment: What kind of processing? There is not a lot of processing you can do with a jpeg stored in MS Access.